# do same calculation over and over in loop with changing variable each time

Tags: python

I want to run this code with several x values and get all the outputs in a list. First run x should be 1, next loop x should be 2, then 3 etc... Is there an easy way to implement this in my code?

EDIT: The loop is now working after i added:

for x in range(1, max_value):

Is there an way I can make a list of the outputs for the degrees of freedom for each loop?

[https://imgur.com/eQxHzHZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Gkq.png)

```
import numpy as np 
import math
from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis, kurtosistest
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm,t
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_excel(r"filename.xlsx",sheet_name,skiprows=x+5,usecols="C")
ret = np.array(data.values)



from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis
X = np.random.randn(10000000)
print(skew(X))
print(kurtosis(X, fisher=False))

# N(x; mu, sig) best fit (finding: mu, stdev)
mu_norm, sig_norm = norm.fit(ret)
dx = 0.0001  # resolution
x = np.arange(-0.1, 0.1, dx)
pdf = norm.pdf(x, mu_norm, sig_norm)
print("Integral norm.pdf(x; mu_norm, sig_norm) dx = %.2f" % (np.sum(pdf*dx)))
print("Sample mean  = %.5f" % mu_norm)
print("Sample stdev = %.5f" % sig_norm)
print()

df = pd.DataFrame(ret)

# Student t best fit (finding: nu)
x = t.fit(ret)
nu, mu_t, sig_t = x
pdf2 = t.pdf(x, nu, mu_t, sig_t)
print("Integral t.pdf(x; mu, sig) dx = %.2f" % (np.sum(pdf2*dx)))
print("nu = %.2f" % nu)
print()
```

Comment: Please note your sheet_name variable is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole code in a `for` loop that increments `x` each time.

```
for x in range(1, max_value):
    #do stuff
    #add value to a list
print(your_list)
```

Side note: maybe add all your imports at the beginning, before any scripts start

**EDIT x2**: as `x` is overwritten, do

```
my_list = []
for my_var in range(1, max_value):
    x = my_var
    #do stuff with x
    #add value to a list
    my_list.append(x)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: This might not work because x gets overridden within the loop.

Comment: in that case use a placeholder variable - I'll update my answer

Comment: Actually I just checked and it seems it would work without renaming... but the safest and clearest would be to either rename just like you propose or put the loop content inside a function and call the function.

Comment: Thanks. I got the loop working.

I want to save all the output from this (the last line in the code):

 print("nu = %.2f" % nu)
    print()

Comment: If it worked for you don't forget to accept the answer, so other people will know the solution https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop :

```
for x in range(n):
    f(x)
```

will call the function f on x with x=0, x=1, all the way to x=n-1.